# Android ProductFlavor name 'plus' doesn't work

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-productflavors

I try to create two different product flavors for my app. One normal flavor for a free version and one flavor called "plus" for a paid version. I tried to create these flavors with the following code in my build.gradle

```
productFlavors {
    normal {}
    plus {
        applicationIdSuffix '.plus'
        versionNameSuffix '-plus'
    }
}
```

Then I noticed that after I synced everything I just saw normalDebug and normalRelease in my buildVariants. I struggled around and just found out as soon as I add any character to plus and sync again it works. So things like plusx work and show all the buildVariants in Android Studio. I couldn't find out why the simple word plus doesn't work. Does anyone know about it and is there a way to use plus as name for my product flavor?

Comment: If you use `plus`, do the variants work from a command-line build? IOW, is this a Gradle/Android Plugin for Gradle problem, or is this an Android Studio problem?

Comment: Nope it isn't even shown in `gradlew tasks`. But I found out that I can get around this problem when I start with an upper letter, like `Plus`. Then everything is working as expected

Comment: Perhaps `plus` is a Groovy keyword or something, and therefore it cannot be used here.

Comment: Okay, guess I'm fine with the capital letter. Thanks for your suggestion regarding the command-line. That made me trying to use capital `P` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @CommonsWare wrote `plus` might be a Groovy keyword or something else. I came across the possibility to use a capital letter like `Plus`. This works as expected.